# Alternative to Latexdiff

Tags: pdftex, overleaf, latexdiff

I need to compare two versions of the latex file of my research papers. I ran latexdiff command as follows:

```
latexdiff old_file.tex new_file.tex > diff_file.tex
```

When I compile the `diff_file.tex` it cannot produce the pdf file due to so many errors, i.e., it is giving error for each equation and table. Latex file is big, so editing the diff file for each equation and table will take a lot of time and there is a deadline. I am looking for a better alternative of latexdiff, which does not get confused with math equations and table.

Can you suggest any such software ?

Comment: Not an answer but have you tried `--math-markup=none` or `--math-markup=whole` with regard to errors in equations. For tables, you could try `--add-to-config PICTURENEV=tabular`   which is supposed to suppress all markup in tabular environments  (you can addi different types of tabular-like environments by adding to above separated by a semi-colon

Comment: Thanks, it works. but with --math-markup=whole again give the same error. However, as far as I have understood, the above command ignores the equation and tabular environment completely. 

How you people mark changes in the tabular environment or equation environment ?

Comment: Most of the times, it works fine with changes in tabular environments and equations.  But some things trip latexdiff up, and then disabling the markup in these cases is a way to get at least a diff for the rest. For example. changing the content of one cell in a tabular environment should work but adding a column will probably fail. I think adding a row will work. 
If you create a minimal example with just the equation or tabular environment that fails then you can post it as a bug report on the latexdiff github page.